# What is the difference between different ways to set the default application in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, gui, default-programs

Let's say I want to change the default GUI and CLI text editor application for all possible 'text' file types. What's the difference between `update-alternatives` way and `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` way to set a default application for both GUI and CLI cases?

Also, compared to the `.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` way?

Also, compared to the `export EDITOR=<editor>` way?

Also, compared to `Right click -> Properties -> Open With -> Set as default` in Nautilus?

Also, compared to the `Default Applications` section in system settings?

Thank you.)

Comment: It seems like `update-alternatives` is used for commands (CLI), while `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` is used for applications (GUI), with `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` being the per-user equivalent. I'm not sure about `$EDITOR`.

Comment: "Set as default" in Nautilus and "Default Applications" in Settings probably use `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`.